# Binary distribution from cmake.org - what to do with the downloaded binaries?

Tags: cmake

After downloading and extracting them, how do I install the CMAKE binary files in Ubuntu 14.04 so that they're recognized with `cmake --version`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need it from cmake.org instead of from Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu installs V2.8 only, i needed >V3.8 for Nordic nRF5 SDK for mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your downloaded cmake on your $PATH, either is $HOME/bin or /usr/local/bin (or /opt and add /opt to your path) and then in setting a path put the location of your downloaded cmake first

For example,

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

would search and find your downloaded cmake first if it were in $HOME/bin or /usr/local/bin respectively.

If you used PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin is would use the system cmake first (due to order of directories in $PATH )

- See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115964/program-installed-to-home-username-bin-and-added-to-path-not-launching

Alternately you can use to full path to your cmake, for example

```
/home/your_user/Downloads/cmake --version
```

or

```
$HOME/bin/cmake --version
```